# Creating admin in imported realm

Tags: keycloak

I've launched keycloak locally from a docker container with

`docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin`

Then I've imported a realm (let's call it `test-realm`) from a json file by `POST`ing to `{keycloak_host}/admin/realms`. This works, the realm is  created.

It's created without any initial users though. I want to create the users via curl as I want to automatize the whole process (start keycloak server, import realm, create users from json) in the future.

I'm aware of `{keycloak_host}/admin/realms/test-realm/users` of course. The problem is that `POST`ing to that end point already requires credentials (e.g. a JWT) from an admin account on `test-realm`. Or am I mistaken in this assumption?

My question is, how do I create that first admin account on `test-realm` having access to an admin on `master`. Or do I even need it to create users on `test-realm` through curl?

Comment: You could also use command line utilities provided by keycloak in <Keycloak-Home>/bin , like add-user.sh

Answer (score 0):

Turned out you can include a `users` key in the json realm representation. The value is an array of user representations as of version 4.5 of keycloak. So problem solved.